# TCP congestion control version: HTCP module vs highspeed module in linux kernel

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel, congestion-control

I found that, in Linux, there are many loadable modules for congestion control algorithms of TCP (cubic, new-reno, veno, vegas,...). But there are two modules that make me confused, one is "HTCP" and the other one is "highspeed". Doesn't HTCP stands for highspeed TCP? So what is the differences between "HTCP" and "highspeed" module here?
Thanks in advance for pointing out the differences.

Comment: I found this one: `Cubic - The default on Linux`, 
   `Reno - The classic TCP protocol. Most OSes use this.`,
   `highspeed - HighSpeed TCP: Sally Floyd's suggested algorithm`,
   `htcp - Hamilton TCP`,
   `hybla - For Satellite Links`,
   `scalable - Scalable TCP`,
   `vegas - Vegas TCP`,
   `westwood - Optimized for lossy networks`,

Comment: here's a good summary of the different TCPs available in Linux : http://linuxgazette.net/135/pfeiffer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't HTCP stands for highspeed TCP?

No. It stands for *TCP for high-speed and long-distance networks* and is described in this [document](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Doug.Leith/pubs/htcp3.pdf) from the Hamilton Institute. *HighSpeed TCP* is published in [RFC 3649](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3649.txt).

> So what is the differences between "HTCP" and "highspeed" module here?

The common point first, is that they want to turn *high bandwidth long distance networks* more efficient. The main difference, is that *HighSpeed TCP* relies on the packet drop rate while *H-TCP* relies on time elapsed since the last packet drop. As a result, H-TCP seems faster to have its *Window Size* to recover after a congestion event, which will then give a higher throughput.